# Using modelForm with CreateView

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have a problem with CreateView. My code is a bit of a frankenstein monster with code from various tutorials, docs, and stackoverflow. I feel like I have misunderstood some fundamental step in the workflow.

Here is the models.py:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                   related_name='customers')
```

Here is the forms.py:

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        name = form.cleaned_data['name'].upper()
        form.cleaned_data['name'] = name

    class Meta:
        model = Customer

        fields = ['name', 'phone']
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            'phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),}
```

Here is the views.py:

```
class CustomerCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Customer
    form_class = CustomerForm
    context_object_name = 'customer_create'
    template_name = 'customers/customer-create.html'
    login_url = 'account_login'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

And lastly here is the template:

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

The problem is that when I hit save the page just refreshes and the new object is not created.
What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
changing form_valid method to this fixed the problem:

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance = form.save(commit=False)
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        form.instance.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

**In forms.py**
fields = ['name', 'phone']
should be replaced by
fields = ('name', 'phone')

Comment: That did not fix it =(